# Initializer list overwrites memory for dynamic multi dimensional array

Tags: c++

Why is the following allowed?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(2,3);

    auto arr = new int[dist(rd)][4][2]{{{1}},{{2}},{{3}}}; // may write to unallocated memory

    auto val1 = arr[0][0][0];
    auto val2 = arr[1][0][0];
    auto val3 = arr[2][0][0];

    auto result = val1 + val2 + val3;
    std::cout << result;

    return 0;
}
```

The initializer will write over unallocated memory if the random value is 2.

Similar to the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7125040/1460794), I would not have expected the compiler to allow this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is required to generate a throw of an exception of type [`bad_array_new_length`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_array_new_length) if there are too many initializers for the array-new expression.

g++ 6.1 does emit a throw of `bad_array_new_length` as expected; clang does not, but this is because it is able to eliminate the allocation ([Clang fails to throw a std::bad_alloc when allocating objects that would exceed the limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22453001/clang-fails-to-throw-a-stdbad-alloc-when-allocating-objects-that-would-exceed)). If the allocation is forced to occur, clang throws an exception but [of the wrong type](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=11644) (`std::bad_alloc`).

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8990c56d2001570):

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_array_new_length'
  what():  std::bad_array_new_length
```