# Visual Studio and Clang do not throw std::bad_array_new_length

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, language-lawyer

This is a follow up to to a [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37573209/1460794).

In the following program Visual Studio 2015 [and Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/143c79643f16035e) both do not throw `std::bad_array_new_length`. [gcc does](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9f9f132cb41d151).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <exception>
#include <new>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(2,2);
    try {

        auto arr = new int[dist(rd)][4][2]{{{1}},{{2}},{{3}}}; // may write to unallocated memory

        auto val1 = arr[0][0][0];
        auto val2 = arr[1][0][0];
        auto val3 = arr[2][0][0];
        auto result = val1 + val2 + val3;
        std::cout << result;
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In Visual Studio the program crashes without any message. In Clang there is no error (perhaps because it [avoided the allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22455263/1460794) as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37573446/1460794)).

Three compilers, three results. Is this undefined behavior or is this is a bug in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC is correct, the behavior is defined by the standard.

`$5.3.4/7 New [expr.new]`

> The expression in a noptr-new-declarator is erroneous if:
>
> ...
>
> (7.4) — the new-initializer is a braced-init-list and the number of
>   array elements for which initializers are provided (including the
>   terminating ’\0’ in a string literal (2.13.5)) exceeds the number of
>   elements to initialize.
>
> ...
>
> a new-expression with an erroneous expression does not call an
>   allocation function and terminates by throwing an exception of a type
>   that would match a handler (15.3) of type `std::bad_array_new_length`
>   (18.6.2.2).