# Why clang works ok with runtime size and initializer list for dynamic array, while gcc (strange behavior) and msvc (internal compiler error) not?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, language-lawyer, new-operator, dynamic-arrays

**I know that modernly raw pointers should be usually avoided, with some exceptions. My question is about an interaction that I saw since I started my studies and I still can't understand it.**

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

#define SIZE_GREATER

int main() {

    #ifdef SIZE_GREATER

    int size = 2;
    //constexpr int size = 10;

    char* a = nullptr;
    a = new char [size] {"text"}; 
    //a = new char [size] {'t','e','x','t','\0'}; 

    std::cout << (void*) a << std::endl; //address
    std::cout << a << std::endl; //gcc: "", clang: "text"
    std::cout << std::strlen(a) << std::endl; //gcc: 0, clang: 4
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(a[0]) << std::endl; //gc:: 0, clang 116 ('t')
    
    #else

    int size = 3;
    char* a = nullptr;

    a = new char [size] {"text"}; //exception run_time
    //a = new char [size] {'t','e','x','t','\0'}; 

    std::cout << (void*) a << std::endl; 
    std::cout << a << std::endl; 
    std::cout << std::strlen(a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(a[0]) << std::endl; 
    
    #endif

    return 0;
}
```

in [demo in godbolt here](https://godbolt.org/z/Wddjc61b5)
(c++20)

---

The problem is to define the size of the array in runtime and use an initializer list with c-string.

With **gcc 12.1**,
if the size of the operand of new[] operator for greater than the size of the initializer, the compilation is ok.However, the output of new[] is strange and is not initialized.

If the size of the new[] for smaller, is throw std::bad_array_new_length runtime (expected)

With **clang 14.0.0**, everything work as expected. If greater, the allocation and initialization is ok. If smaller, is throw std::bad_alloc.

With **msvc 19.latest**, there is internal compiler error (fatal error C1001: Internal compiler error).

With **msvc and gcc**, if the size is compiler-time (constexpr/const int size = 10;), everything works fine. If the initializer list is **{'t','e','x','t','\0'}**, everything works fine.

With **msvc**, if the size is compiler-time and is less than the of the initializer, strangely is not thrown an expection.

---

From my revision of the [specs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new), the expected behavior is "the first size can be runtime. If the new expression have an initializer with more elements than the size, throw exception **std::bad_array_new_length**:

> If type is an array type, all dimensions **other than the first** must be
> specified as positive integral constant expression (until
> C++14)converted constant expression of type std::size_t (since C++14)
> [...]
> **This is the only way to directly create an array with size defined at runtime**, such arrays are often referred to as dynamic arrays:
> [...]

and

> In the following cases the expression specifying the first dimension
> is erroneous:
>
> [,,,]
>
> the value is smaller than the number of array
> elements provided in the brace-enclosed initializer (including > the terminating '\0' on a string literal).

with

> If the value in the first dimension is erroneous for any of these
> reasons,
>
> [...]
>
> **Otherwise, the new-expression does not call the allocation function, and instead throws an exception of type std::bad_array_new_length or
> derived from it**

**Why the results are so strange, including between compilers?**

With compiler-time size, oddly the results are ok.
From what I understand, clang is the one who have the correct behavior in front of the spec, but I would like to hear the opinion of someone more experienced. Thanks.

---

**EDIT START**

(I noticed that I wrote the wrong code, it was for the size variable have value LARGER than the initialization list. I wrote in both cases having smaller value. Sorry for the **big mess**.)

1 When we use new[] with size run-time and initialize with form c-string literal, and the size is LARGER than the size of the c-string literal

1.1 Gcc compile,however don't initialize the array of new[].

output:

```
0x1b83eb0

(empty)

0

0
```

1.2 Msvc throws internal compiler error.

output:

```
<source>(9): fatal error C1001: Internal compiler error.
```

1.3 Clang compile and initialize the array of new[].

output:

```
0x2409eb0

text

4

116
```

The code:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int size = 10;

    char* a = nullptr;
    a = new char [size] {"text"}; 

    std::cout << (void*) a << std::endl; //address
    std::cout << a << std::endl; //gcc: "", clang: "text"
    std::cout << std::strlen(a) << std::endl; //gcc: 0, clang: 4
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(a[0]) << std::endl; //gc:: 0, clang 116 ('t')
    
    //msvc: internal compiler error
    return 0;
}
```

in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9bhvosa6Y)

From my interpretation (quotes above), clang has the correct behavior and both others compilers are wrong. Is my interpretation corret?

2º Question: Msvc didn't throw exception bad_alloc when new[] size was smaller than the size of the initializer list

As said by the comment of LanguageLawyer, dont throw exception bad_alloc sometimes on new expression is a known bug [answered]

[for visual studio and clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37574449/visual-studio-and-clang-do-not-throw-stdbad-array-new-length)

[for gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65350)

**EDIT END**

Comment: "test" needs a size of 5, you declare 2. If you want an array of C-strings, the type is `char**`.

Comment: `a = new char [size] {"text"}; ` has undefined behavior.  Trying to reason about the results of that is kind of usless as the behavior can change at any moment

Comment: You should also decide on your language. If you want C++, this code can be **greatly** simplified.

Comment: The "strange" behavior is because the behavior is *undefined*. The compilers are allowed to do anything, and anything could happen when you run the code, including (but not limited to) strange behavior, crashes, or summoning [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: I understand, it is undefined behavior. However, I searched the specifications (cppreference) and found nothing clearly, except for this: "Otherwise, the new-expression does not call the allocation function, and instead throws an exception of type std::bad_array_new_length or derived from it". Wouldn't that define the behavior or am I interpreting wrong? (Thanks for your attention, anyway)

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65350. Funny that gcc was able to work correct some time ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37574449/visual-studio-and-clang-do-not-throw-stdbad-array-new-length

Comment: _I understand, it is undefined behavior_ You point at an explicit definition of behavior and understand that it is undefined? Did you decide to join the retardation train headed by NathanOliver and Some programmer dude?

Comment: Dup of [Visual Studio and Clang do not throw std::bad\_array\_new\_length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37574449/visual-studio-and-clang-do-not-throw-stdbad-array-new-length)

Comment: English is not my first language, so I am not very confident in my interpretation. I understood that it is bug not to throw bad_alloc in this case (I realized this later because it was not my initial doubt). But what about the behavior of the GCC when the size is legal and greather than the initialization list? Don't should It behave as expected? MSVC does not even compile (Please be kind to us)

Comment: You are discussing too many things all at once, it is difficult to keep track. Please show ONE program that has ONE behaviour which you don't understand.

Comment: I wrote the wrong code, forgot to correct the value of the first. I separated the two problems and I wrote the correct code for the unanswered yet (Sorry for the Big Mess. I wanted the first to have higher value and the second the lowest value, but I wrote both with the smallest).